# How do I optimize this nested group by sql statement?

Tags: sql, optimization, group-by, query-optimization, temp-tables

EDIT: Just changed the alias' on the last sql statement so they are distinct and clear - had an `a` repeated within the nested statements.

Some context:
First, I am taking some data from a separate database (on a different server), doing some manipulation outside of the db, then sending that data into a temp table in this form:

The PKID and WordID make up a composite key on the data (the word ID has been derived during the data manipulation) - this comes to about 300k rows in this format:

| FromPK | WordID | sometext |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 2 | B |
| 1 | 3 | C |
| 2 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 2 | B |
| 2 | 4 | D |

Then, I am running these queries - first straight into second:

```sql
select a.FromPK, b.ToPK, count(*) as wordcount
into #temp2 
from #temp1 a 
inner join TableFoo b on a.WordID = b.WordID
group by a.FromPK, b.ToPK
```

```sql
select a.ID, a.Col1, a.Col2, b.pkid, c.sometext
from TableBar a inner join (
    select b.*, c.pkid from (
        select pkid, max(wordcount) as maxwordcount from 
            #temp2 group by pkid
        ) b join #temp2 c on b.pkid = c.pkid where b.wordcount = c.maxwordcount
    ) d on a.ID = d.pkid join #temp1 e on d.pkid = e.pkid
```

I can do these on one statement (by nesting the first statement in place of `#temp2` on the second) - but in either case, it is very slow. Any way of optimizing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL and optimization techniques. Please add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?  To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL optimization can be either in the query or in the way the server save the database. In your case I would create the temp tables with a index-key `pkid` because you are using inner join on that field. it seem that you can chose `ID` as a primary key. after doing so, I guess you will get a better performance.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...);
```

Comment: Yeah, the non-temp tables are indexed up. Didn't think to do that on the temp tables to be honest, I'll give that a go.